# How to get property value from another properties file

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

Application-properties
Username=${local-properties.USERNAME}

local-properties
USERNAME=abc123

Is the above possible?

Reason: I want to add local-properties to gitognore, so sensitive info isnt uploaded to github, also i wanna know the property names so I did not add application properties to gitignore. I don't wanna use env variables because it is tied to the os,machine...

Used file, didn't work

I have searched many questions and answers and most of them said to use OS env variables like JAVA_HOME, I don't want it to be tied to the machine, how about a file